# Eclipse: fixing 'Redundant specification of type arguments' result in an error

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse (Oxygen.2) shows the 'Redundant specification of type arguments' warning for the code snippet below. When I fix it, by using `new Element<>()`, I get a compile time error on the next line, because it doesn't infer the type, it uses `Element<Object>` instead and the list is `Element<A>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  List<Element<A>> list = new ArrayList<>();
  Stream.of("foo", "bar")
    .map(e -> new Element<A>())
    .forEach(list::add);
}

interface A
{}

private static class Element<A>
{
  public Element()
  {}
}
```

IntelliJ doesn't suggest removing the type. Is this a problem of Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 1.8.0.74.

Comment: You're not doing it right anyway. To put elements in a list use `collect(Collectors.toList())`, not `forEach`, and assign the result to `list`.

Comment: Seems OK in Eclipse Photon (with Java 10) so possibly a problem in Oxygen that has been fixed.

Comment: @RealSkeptic. I know, this was a simplification of a large piece of code, I just took the essence of it.

Comment: @greg-449, thanks! I'll update my Eclipse then.

Comment: Updated to Photon, but I still have the same issue. Java 10 is not an option for me, but maybe a newer 1.8.